# Indicator for a 360 image rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple 360 image rotator that cycles through a series of images to create the effect of rotating an object. I want to add an indicator that shows users that you can rotate the object that fades out after the fist image has been past. So I added this function to the end of my `360.js`

```
(function(){
     if(
$('#first').css('visibility','hidden')) {
    $('#rotate').fadeOut();
} 
else {
    $('#rotate').fadeIn();
}

     });
```

Theres no error in the script, it's just not checking to see if the image is visible or not. I tried binding it to mousedown and mousemove events called in my `360.js` but with no luck. Any one have any ideas on how to resolve this? 
**[Heres a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7WmA/1/)**

Comment: I'm confused, do you just want to change the cursor to indicate that you can rotate the image?

Comment: Here's a partial fix: http://jsfiddle.net/y7WmA/4/ .  I named your function, and tossed it into your document mouse callback.  I fixed the `if` statement - you're not checking if it's hidden in that line, you're **setting** it to hidden.  I added some console messages to show that it's seeing hidden and visible when appropriate.  The fadein is still not working, but maybe you can take it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was one major problem beside what I listed on my comments.

You're setting currentImage to 1, instead of 0, and the indexing is 0 based.  So the image you want is never again visible, so fading in never happens.

I also check whether it has the class 'notseen', though checking for hidden should have been just as good.

Here's my latest fix, and you should see it generally works: http://jsfiddle.net/y7WmA/6/

And here are the significant snippets:

```
.bind('mousemove touchmove', function (e) {
    fadeInOut();
    // ...
        if (Math.abs(currPos - pageX) >= widthStep) {
            if (currPos - pageX >= widthStep) {
                currImg++;
                if (currImg > imageTotal) {
                    currImg = 0;
                }
            } else {
                currImg--;
                if (currImg < 0) {
                    currImg = imageTotal;
                }
            }
// ...
function fadeInOut() {
    if ($('#first').hasClass('notseen')) {
        console.log("hidden");
        $('#rotate').fadeOut();
    } else {
       console.log("visible");
        $('#rotate').fadeIn();
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the tricky things about JSFiddle is where it places your scripts. It seems your script was having difficulty binding the event to the DOM, since JSFiddle was loading it immediately upon page load. This may or may not have had something to do with what you experienced locally.

Nevertheless, I've slightly modified your JSFiddle here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7WmA/5/). Notice that I've add a firstMove boolean, which then either enables or disables the following script:

```
   if (!firstMove) {
        $('#rotate').fadeOut()
        firstMove = true;
    }
```

Your placeholder fades out immediately after first movement. Ultimately, I'd like to find a way to avoid using a boolean tracker, but this should get you headed in the right direction!

EDIT: Also note that your current version is performing the evaluation everytime movement occurs on the image, which can be costly especially when using jQuery selectors.